# Trying to create a function with a variable PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to do something like this:

```
//function name

$str = 'bla()';


//make function with string as name
function $str{
      echo 'yey';
}

//Call the function by string name
bla();
```

Comment: what you will need is http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php but don't use it if you don't have to.

Comment: Why would you do such a silly thing?

Comment: Maybe this is what you are after? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php

Comment: For what it's worth you don't need to use eval() to call a function using the $funcName() syntax.

Comment: It is for wordpress. i can't find another way. All these answers are wrong. So this means i need to find another way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `eval()` to attempt this task. But I really do **NOT** suggest it:

```
// name of the function
$str = 'bla';
// php code you want to execute inside
$inside = '';
eval("
    function $str() { $inside }
");
```

Or you could also use an anonymous function:

```
$name = function() {
    // code
};
// execution
$name();
```

Als if you are just trying to call a dynamic function just use `call_user_func()` like this:

```
// name of the function
$str = 'bla';
// paramters to the function
$param = array();
call_user_func($str, $param);
```

But I think you are doing something wrong. This kind of "hacks" are sign of bad application architecture.

**References**

- [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)
- [call_user_func()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)
- [Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Comment: It is for wordpress dynamically include modules. i didn't found another way to do this. add_submenu_page() needs to have a function with the content in it. so for every module it needs a new function. in the function it includes the page.

i still hope i am not making "bad application structure" because this isn't the way i usually are programming

Answer (score 3):

I'll suggest you, not to use like this. But if still you want to do this,

```
<?php
$greet = function($name)
{
    printf("Hello %s\r\n", $name);
};

$greet('World');
$greet('PHP');
?>
```

[Check here](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

And you are required to use PHP 5.3

Answer (score -2):

Whenever a function completes, it RETURNS a value.  If no value is set to be returned, 0 is returned.

If you would like to be able to do as you have asked, you could do the following:

```
function blah($string="Blah"){
return($string);
}


echo blah("Banana");  //echo's Banana
echo blah(); //echo's Blah
$str = blah("Apple"); //Sets $str to Apple
```